# How to modify the output path in the PreBuildEvent or BeforeBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I am using the following code in the `BeforeBuild` event:

```
<XmlPeek XmlInputPath="SiteSettings.config" Query="appSettings/add[@key='cProjectNumber']/@value">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="value" />
</XmlPeek>
<PropertyGroup>
  <ProjectNumber>0@(value)</ProjectNumber>
</PropertyGroup>
```

which then gives me access to `$(ProjectNumber)` which will contain a project number like `1234`. I then use this to include some project specific overrides on classes. This is working fine.

My issue is accessing `ProjectNumber` outside of the `BeforeBuild` event.

What I would like to do is to modify the `<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>` of the project so it goes into a project specific folder (so I know which builds are done). I tried `<OutputPath>bin\$(ProjectNumber)\</OutputPath>` but I assume my property is out of scope as it's empty.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve what I want?

EDIT: This is what I have tried with declaring a global var:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTarget="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectNumber></ProjectNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(ProjectNumber)\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <XmlPeek XmlInputPath="SiteSettings.config" Query="appSettings/add[@key='cProjectNumber']/@value">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="value" />
    </XmlPeek>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ProjectNumber>0@(value)</ProjectNumber>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="Accounts\$(ProjectNumber)\Objects\MyObject.cs">
        <SubType>Code</SubType>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="Proj:$(ProjectNumber)" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

AfterBuild has the correct project number message printed but `<OutputPath>bin\$(ProjectNumber)\</OutputPath>` doesn't have the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a Property in the Project Global level with the name `ProjectNumber` and empty value as a place holder. The the `ProjectNumber` Property value you set in the `InitializeBuild` target will set the global level property of `ProjectNumber`.

By looking at the sample below you can understand it better:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" InitialTargets="InitializeBuild" DefaultTargets="All" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectNumber></ProjectNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="All">
    <Message Text="This is the value after I set it in InitializeBuild '$(ProjectNumber)'"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="This is the value before I set it in InitializeBuild '$(ProjectNumber)'"/>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ProjectNumber>12345678</ProjectNumber>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

In this sample, we are setting Property `ProjectNumber` with empty value at Global level and then in `InitializeBuild` target, it is set with value `12345678` as `InitializeBuild` is part of the `InitialTargets` and then through `DefaultTargets` later, once it is accessed in target `All` it is having the value `12345678`.

The output of the above code goes as below:

```
>msbuild mybuild.msbuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 9/25/2013 5:35:22 AM.
Project "D:\CodeBase\COLNEW\COL-BIS\dev\mybuild.msbuild" on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuild:
  This is the value before I set it in InitializeBuild''
All:
  This is the value after I set it in InitializeBuild'12345678'
Done Building Project "D:\CodeBase\COLNEW\COL-BIS\dev\mybuild.msbuild" (default targets).
```

So your issue can be solved in similar fashion.

Comment: This sounds very promising. I tried as you suggested above and set `<OutputPath>bin\$(ProjectNumberBin)\</OutputPath>` but it didn't seem to work. I'm not sure where `Target Name="All"` would tie in.

Comment: Target `All` is just given by me to show that it is accessible anywhere outside `BeforeBuild` with the values set in `BeforeBuid`. In your case whiever target `<OutputPath>bin\$(ProjectNumber)\</OutputPath>` is present should be equivalent of my sample's `All` target.

Comment: Could you see my edit please and let me know what you think. The only difference I can see is the project line declaration but I have tried playing with it with no success.

Comment: As in your case the `OutputPath` is processing the value of it in project global section which comes before in execution than `BeforeBuild` (where the value of `ProjectNumber` is initialized), it is difficult to get the value of `OutputPath` as you are expecting.

Comment: One thing you can try is that you can add a new target `InitializeBuild` as I updated in the answer instead of doing this `ProjectNumber` initialization in `BeforeBuild` and call that new target in `InitialTargets="InitializeBuild"` in `Project` tag. If that is also not working, the only option I can see is that you should declare `OutputPath` in global section and initialize the value of that as well in `BeforeBuild` target after the `ProjectNumber` value is set.